# Nvidia Surround, change "profile"

Tags: nvidia-graphics-card, eyefinity

I have the Nvidia surrond setup, with 3 monitors. And my problem is switching from surround mode to normal windows mode.

I used to have eyeinfity, and there you could create simple profiles to swap between eyeinfinty and normal monitor operation.

For those that dont know, basicly the way this tech works it creates a virutal monitor thats the resolution over all the monitors. this is great in games, but when your in windows maximising IE over 3 monitors is annoying

Comment: Basically nVidia's implementation of this stuff is terrible - sometimes I have trouble even getting it to enable in practice!  I tend to prefer them for hardware as a rule, but if you need this functionality EyeFinity is the way to go.